# How to get all files inside an IProject

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-jdt

I want to list out all files inside a java project using jdt, including jsps, xml files, etc.

I have tried the below code, but it returns java resources only (including class files, which I don't require).

```
    List<String> resourceNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    IProject[] projects = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getProjects();

    for (IProject project : projects) {

        if (project.isOpen() && project.isNatureEnabled(JavaCore.NATURE_ID)) {

            for (IResource resource : project.members()) {
                resourceNames.add(resource.getName() + "-" + resource.getFullPath().toString());
            }
        }
    }
```

Can anyone please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

'members()' does return everything which is directly in the current container. To see all files you need to look in the folders in each container as well.

Something like:

```
void processContainer(IContainer container)
{
   IResource [] members = container.members();

   for (IResource member : members)
    {
      if (member instanceof IContainer) 
       {
         processContainer((IContainer)member);
       }
      else if (member instanceof IFile)
       {
         ... deal with the file
       }
    }
}
```

Since `IProject` extends `IContainer` just call

```
processContainer(project);
```

to look at everything.

`IContainer` (actually `IResource`) also has several `accept` methods to traverse the container contents calling a callback.

Comment: Thanks again Greg.. that works perfect..!! Any idea how class files can be excluded?

Comment: Excluded classes using the following code: `member instanceof IFile && !member.isDerived()`

Comment: how can I get the contents of the files obtained in this way?

Comment: @ArturS.Farias - That is a new question - ask a Question